# How to get current caller/principal in JMX mbean?

Tags: security, wildfly, jmx, principal

I have one case which works on JBoss 4.2.

1. Client login (with JAAS, ClientLoginModule)
2. Client get JMX connection from JBoss JMX server
3. Client call mbean API;

Server will check current caller/principal is, whether he/she has the enough privilege to do the action.

Now with Wildfly 9, we do the similar thing, moreover, we have set the username/password when getting JMX connection.

```
// urlString likes:service:jmx:remote://localhost:9999
JMXServiceURL serviceURL = new JMXServiceURL(urlString);
Map<String, Object> env = new HashMap<String, Object>();
String[] creds = new String[2];
creds[0] = username_;
creds[1] = password_;
env.put(JMXConnector.CREDENTIALS, creds);
JMXConnector jmxConnector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(serviceURL, env);
MBeanServerConnection connection = jmxConnector.getMBeanServerConnection();
```

However, at step3, JMX server find current caller/principal is null.

Do you know why? Or how to resolve this.

Are there any interceptors for JMX just like EJB?